# "v.context.$implicit.categories[0] is undefined" error in Ionic 3

Tags: wordpress, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to access the category slug for a product in ionic using the WordPress rest API. This seems to work fine on one page as `<h3 class="product-name uppercase">{{productdetail?.categories[0].slug}}</h3>` however this does not seems to work when i try implementing the same using for loop in angular on another page

```
<div class="width50" *ngFor="let object of dataList">
    <img src="{{object.images[0].src}}" width="150"  (click)="navigateToPage(object.id)" />
    <h3 class="product-name uppercase" text-nowrap>{{object?.categories[0].slug}}</h3> 
</div>
```

it gives an error as `v.context.$implicit.categories[0] is undefined` however on same page the code for image source seems to work fine.

Comment: object?.categories?[0].slug

Comment: @Milad does not work generates "Template parse errors:Parser Error: Conditional expression object?.categories?[0].slug requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression.

Comment: `object?.categories[0]?.slug`

Comment: @yurzui Thanks that worked could you please answer the same and also please explain the concept of inserting "?" symbol. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic Error v.context.$implicit is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008316/ionic-error-v-context-implicit-is-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient
>   way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths. Here
>   it is, protecting against a view render failure if the currentHero is
>   null.

This way if write

```
obj?.foo
```

angular will transform it to the following expression.

```
obj == null ? null : obj.foo
```

so if the `obj` is empty value then you won't see any of errors.

In your case you can use the expresion

```
object?.categories[0]?.slug
```

that will be transformed to

```
object == null ? null : object.categories[0] == null ? null : object.categories[0].slug;
```

Safe navigation operator is helpful if you don't know whether your object contains any value or not, or you load data asynchronously and your object is `undefined` at first time.

Comment: It would be great if you could view some of my other questions too about ionic and could help.