# Ionic Error v.context.$implicit is undefined

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, implicit

I have the error in my code. 
The error says like this:
v.context.$implicit is undefined

The problem is, sometimes it error, and sometimes it doesn’t…
Can somebody explain why it happen…

This my html code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let time of item.timeInfo | keys" >
    <ion-row *ngIf="time == thisDay"> 
      <ion-col col-3 no-padding>
        <ng-container *ngIf="checkTime(); else closeButton">
          <button small ion-button block color="secondary" outline> OPEN </button>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #closeButton>
          <button small ion-button block color="danger" outline>Close </button>
        </ng-template>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-9 >
        {{ item.timeInfo[thisDay].open }} - {{ item.timeInfo[thisDay].close }}
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ng-container>
```

Here my json code:

```
"item":{
   "timeInfo": {
            "Sat": {
                "open": "11:00",
                "close": "21:00"
            },
            "Sun": {
                "open": "9:00",
                "close": "21:30"
            },
            "Mon": {
                "open": "11:00",
                "close": "22:30"
            },
            "Tue": {
                "open": "12:00",
                "close": "22:00"
            },
            "Web": {
                "open": "12:00",
                "close": "22:30"
            },
            "Thu": {
                "open": "9:30",
                "close": "22:30"
            },
            "Fri": {
                "open": "12:30",
                "close": "22:00"
            }
        },
 };
```

And here my version:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.15.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.15.2

local packages:
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:
Node : v6.11.2
npm  : 5.4.2
OS   : Windows 8.1

Misc:
backend : pro
```

Can somebody help me??
Tyvm

Comment: In my case, it was an undefined item in the collection.

Answer (score 3):

i can't really help if i don't see you're TS code. 
The same problem occured to me and my mistake was to try to insert a new data in an array like `result[i] = data[i]` and not like `result.push(data[i])` which is actually correct. Hope it helps !

Comment: I had a similar issue because I was trying to operate on an array which was null, without checking it first.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, `context.$implicit` refer in the template to a variable created with a "let" (like "let time of item.info").

The rest of the error ("is undefined") is the classic javascript error message for trying to use a undefined value like an object.

In your case, it probably happen when the variable `thisDay` is not one of the key of `timeinfo`. checking the exact line of the error will probably help finding the error in the html.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, solved it like this: was - became

```
<button *ngIf="!readOnly && file.length">Remove</button> // error
<button *ngIf="!readOnly && (file && file.length)">Remove</button> //no error
```