# How to delete items of nested objects // ERROR TypeError: "_v.context.$implicit is undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, nested, ngfor, angular2-changedetection

I have a list of objects, which is shown with ngFor and ngSwitchCase. Adding items to the objects as well as removing the object itself is no problem.
But If I try to remove items nested inside the object, this error shows up:

> ERROR TypeError: "_v.context.$implicit is undefined"

The objects is/seems gone, because the information is not displayed, but the div's aka design/rendering with ngFor is messed up. (I'm using Angular8.)

Here is a slimmed down version of my problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjsvzh

In the Stackblitz example, i get another error though, trying the same:

> ERROR TypeError: "this.articles[0].content[boxId] is undefined"

I just dont get why when I remove the object, "delete" works perfectly, but the other time it doesn't.

```
closeContentBox(boxId) {
    console.log('I close contentBoxes');
    delete this.articles[0].content[boxId];
  }

  removeItemBox(boxId, itemId) {
    console.log('I remove itemBoxes');
    delete this.articles[0].content[boxId].data.items[itemId];  
  }
```

maybe related, but didnt help:
[implicit context is undefined, angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793202/implicit-context-is-undefined-angular-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 removeItemBox(boxId, itemId) {
// delete this.articles[0].content[boxId].data.texts[itemId];  
this.articles[0].content[boxId].data.texts.splice(itemId, 1);}
```

also in the html, make change to the first argument like so:

```
<div class="removeButton" (click)="removeItemBox(boxId, itemId)
```

Comment: I found it also myself, just an hour after asking. Apparently this time, splice does the job, because it acts on an array. whereas for the contentbox, its an object, which is handled differently.

Comment: Thanks for marking it as an answer even tho you found the issue yourself!